# где-то(,) у кого-то

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В интернете есть предложения, в которых "где-то(,) у кого-то" через запятую пишется, и есть предложения, где запятой нет.

Примеры:

1. Не исключено, что наш очеркист где-то, у кого-то вычитал о маниловщине, в известной степени свойственной и круто-суровому Романову, и не чуждому сантиментов Бенкендорфу, но вычитанное, чужое, как нередко бывает, ассоциировалось со своим, личным, услышанным, наблюденным.
2. Если где-то у кого-то совесть нечиста, как поется в песне.
3. Князь был дилетант-художник, где-то, у кого-то учился за границей.
4. Гм!.. Где-то у кого-то уже готовы выводы.
5. Думаю, «Блоху» театр разрешит только перепечатать ― своего экземпляра (у нас остался только один) не выдает ― «Ночное» и «Помолвка» где-то у кого-то гуляют.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я бы вообще нигде не поставила запятую, ни в одном из пяти приведённых мною примеров!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, запятые там нигде не требуются.

*Она была в Москве [где-то] у сестры [у кого-то].*
Здесь ещё можно поставить запятую, чтобы сделать уточнение.

Но "у кого-то" почти ничего не уточняет. Вероятность запятой ещё меньше.

Для запятой нужна однородность, а её нет. Разве что можно сделать уточнение:
*Вы не видели указку? Она была где-то, у кого-то.* || Заметная пауза. Присоединение. Но здесь многоточие больше подходит.

Comment: Вот... А в Нацкорпусе есть запятые. Спасибо за ответ. Стрелочку вверх нажать не удаётся, т.к. требуется регистрация, которая тоже не удаётся. Короче, по техническим причинам. Сорри...

Comment: В Нацкорпусе очень много ошибок. Но он хороший помощник, чтобы узнать частотность и понять ситуацию по части стилистики. Можно войти через аккаунт Гугл или другие, делал так, потому что тоже было непросто зарегистрироваться.

Comment: Можно временную почту (temp mail) попробовать. Там нет фильтрации писем.

Comment: У меня сейчас приняло с первой попытки, самое первое [отсюда](https://www.temp-mails.com/). Там баг какой-то: оно хочет очень надёжный пароль, но восклицательный знак пишет возле почты, хотя она подходит.

Comment: Только что попробовала. Система пишет снова следующее: You cannot register at this time.
If you continue to find this error, contact us.

Comment: Может, санкции? Может, через VPN попробовать?

Comment: Это сложно, но я потихонечку пробовать буду. Спасибо за желание помочь!